Withdrawal profits
Ok so let’s say I buy a one bitcoin for 90k it peaks at 94k I withdraw the profit of 4K .if then it drops to 93k does that mean I now have a profit of 3k still or do I have to wait for it to drop back to the original price I paid for it being 90k and for it to peak again to make another profit ?? Need some clarity thanks heaps

You start with 90000 USD.

You have 90000 USD

You buy 1 BTC at a rate of 90000 USD/BTC

You have 1 BTC

The exchange rate rises to 94000 USD/BTC.

You have 1 BTC

You sell the 1 BTC for USD at a rate of 94000 USD/BTC.

You have 94000 USD

The exchange rate drops to 93000 USD/BTC.

You have 94000 USD

Unless you bought BTC again, you didn't lose anything.

The heart of your misunderstanding is "withdraw profits".
Once you have the reality clear in your head, the rest is simple arithmetic, the sort of adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing you learned when you were a small child.

Lets do some adding, subtracting multiplying and dividing  ...



Holdings
$ value
₿ value




$90k
90,000
1


₿0
0
0


Totals
90,000
1




I buy a one bitcoin for 90k




Holdings
$ value
₿ value




$0
0
0


₿1
90,000
1


Totals
90,000
1




it peaks at 94k




Holdings
$ value
₿ value




$0
0
0


₿1
94,000
1


Totals
94,000
1




I withdraw the profit of 4K.

When you "withdraw the profit" what you are doing is selling some of your Bitcoin for dollars at the current exchange rate. After you have sold some of  your Bitcoin you have $4k but you now have less than 1 Bitcoin!
If the exchange rate is $94k = ₿1 then $4k = 4000 / 94000 = ₿0.042553191
To get the $4k you perceive as "profit" into your hands you have to sell ₿0.042553191 of your Bitcoin.
That means you now have ₿1 - ₿0.042553191 = ₿0.957446809



Holdings
$ value
₿ value




$4,000
4,000
0.042553191


₿0.957446809
90,000
0.957446809


Totals
94,000
1



In reality you also pay Bitcoin transaction fees to Bitcoin miners and probably pay conversion charges to the currency exchange. Most currency exchanges have "spread" or difference between their buying and selling rates. Most probably also have some other fee. It has probably been thus since people started making coins thousands of years ago. This is nothing new or special.


if then it drops to 93k does that mean [confused stuff]

If the exchange rate changes to ₿1 = $93k then

your ₿0.957446809 is worth 0.957446809 * 93000 = $89,042.55
your $4k is worth 4000 / 93000 =  ₿0.043010753




Holdings
$ value
₿ value




$4,000
4,000
0.043010753


₿0.957446809
89,042.55
0.957446809


Totals
93,042.55
1.000457562





Need some clarity

All the above is nothing to do with Bitcoin, the sums would be the same if you were were buying and selling diamonds or carrots. It is nothing to do with complex finance. There is no more to it than simple arithmetic.
"Withdrawing Profit" is not some deep mysterious magic. It just means selling some of something you own.
